# What's the UK equivalent of the Better Business Bureau?

Tags: seo

I am currently reading "SEO 2019" by Adam Clarke, and I was reading about signing up to the Better Business Bureau to help with link building.

I am based in the UK - what is the equivalent here? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 3):

Better Business Bureau (BBB) serves consumers and business users and there is no direct equivalent in the UK.

For consumers, there is [Trading Standards](https://www.gov.uk/find-local-trading-standards-office) and [Citizen's Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) (who offer [consumer advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/)).

For businesses, the closest equivalent is probably a [professional trade association](https://www.ukecc-services.net/ukpbata.cfm) or another [membership body](https://memberwise.org.uk/influence100/). There are also supplier directories such as [MemberWise](https://memberwise.org.uk/directory/) and [great.gov.uk](https://www.great.gov.uk/international/trade/).

For link building, you could try joining a professional trade association or supplier directory that offers a public listing of their members. These organisations are generally smaller than BBB and do not have a similar cachet, though. I would expect other SEO activities such as content marketing to have a higher impact on your search traffic.